# How to pass in valid values into cleartext_keyset_json to create a Tink key

Tags: python, cryptography, tink

In Tink, it is possible to load and write cleartext keysets as jsons. An non-working example is seen below:

```
{
  "primaryKeyId": 2800579,
  "key": [
    {
      "keyData": {
        "typeUrl": "type.googleapis.com/google.crypto.tink.AesGcmKey",
        "value": "ODA9eJX9wcAGwZocL0Jym==",
        "keyMaterialType": "SYMMETRIC"
      },
      "status": "ENABLED",
      "keyId": 2800579,
      "outputPrefixType": "TINK"
    }
  ]
}
```

My question is- is it possible to insert your own values into the various key/value pairs to get another valid keyset? I have experimented with this and haven't had much success- mainly because of the "value" key which complains `INVALID_ARGUMENT: Could not parse key_data.value as key type 'type.googleapis.com/google.crypto.tink.AesGcmKey'` Any idea of what a valid "value" would be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, the Base64 string of the *value* field in the posted code snippet is invalid, possibly a copy/paste error.

The following Python code uses [Tink version 1.5.0](https://pypi.org/project/tink/) and creates and displays a keyset for AES-256/GCM as JSON:

```python
import io
from tink import aead
from tink import tink_config
from tink import JsonKeysetWriter
from tink import new_keyset_handle
from tink import cleartext_keyset_handle

tink_config.register()

key_template = aead.aead_key_templates.AES256_GCM
keyset_handle = new_keyset_handle(key_template)

string_out = io.StringIO()
writer = JsonKeysetWriter(string_out)
cleartext_keyset_handle.write(writer, keyset_handle)

serialized_keyset = string_out.getvalue();
print(serialized_keyset);
```

The result is similar to the KeySet you posted and is e.g.:

```json
{
  "primaryKeyId": 1794775293,
  "key": [
    {
      "keyData": {
        "typeUrl": "type.googleapis.com/google.crypto.tink.AesGcmKey",
        "value": "GiD5ojApaIM2MRpPhGf5sVMhxeA6NE5KjdzUxsJ0ChH/JA==",
        "keyMaterialType": "SYMMETRIC"
      },
      "status": "ENABLED",
      "keyId": 1794775293,
      "outputPrefixType": "TINK"
    }
  ]
}
```

I haven't found a documentation that describes the structure in general or for the *value* field, but comparing the generated KeySets for different algorithms allows conclusions. If *value* is hex encoded, the result is:

```
1a20f9a23029688336311a4f8467f9b15321c5e03a344e4a8ddcd4c6c2740a11ff24
```

For AES-256/GCM it has 34 bytes, where the last 32 bytes are the actual key. The beginning is characteristic for the algorithm, the second byte indicates the size of the key, e.g. *0x1a10* for AES-128/GCM, *0x1a20* for AES-256/GCM or *0x1220* for ChaCha20Poly1305 (but can be more complex depending on the algorithm).

To use a self-defined key for AES-256/GCM, e.g.

```
000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f
```

prepend *0x1a20*, Base64 encode the result:

```
GiAAAQIDBAUGBwgJCgsMDQ4PEBESExQVFhcYGRobHB0eHw==
```

and apply this value instead of the old value in the above KeySet.

The modified KeySet can be loaded and used for encryption as follows:

```python
from tink import JsonKeysetReader
from tink import cleartext_keyset_handle

serialized_keyset = '''
{
  "primaryKeyId": 1794775293,
  "key": [
    {
      "keyData": {
        "typeUrl": "type.googleapis.com/google.crypto.tink.AesGcmKey",
        "value": "GiAAAQIDBAUGBwgJCgsMDQ4PEBESExQVFhcYGRobHB0eHw==",
        "keyMaterialType": "SYMMETRIC"
      },
      "status": "ENABLED",
      "keyId": 1794775293,
      "outputPrefixType": "TINK"
    }
  ]
}   
'''
reader = JsonKeysetReader(serialized_keyset)
keyset_handle = cleartext_keyset_handle.read(reader)

plaintext = b'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
aead_primitive = keyset_handle.primitive(aead.Aead)
tink_ciphertext = aead_primitive.encrypt(plaintext, b'')
```

The relationship between KeySet and the example key *0001...1e1f* can be verified by decrypting the generated ciphertext using the example key *without* Tink, e.g. with PyCryptodome.

The format of the Tink ciphertext is described in [*Tink Wire Format, Crypto Formats*](https://github.com/google/tink/blob/v1.5.0/docs/WIRE-FORMAT.md#crypto-formats). The first byte specifies the version, the next 4 bytes the key ID, followed by the actual data.
For GCM the actual data has the format *nonce (12 bytes) || ciphertext || tag (16 bytes)*. Decryption is then possible with (using PyCryptodome):

```python
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

key = bytes.fromhex('000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f')

prefix = tink_ciphertext[:5]
nonce = tink_ciphertext[5:5 + 12]
ciphertext = tink_ciphertext[5 + 12:-16]
tag = tink_ciphertext[-16:]

cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM, nonce=nonce)
cipher.update(b'')
decryptedText = cipher.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, tag)

print(decryptedText.decode('utf-8')) # The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

which proves that the example key *0001...1e1f* was correctly integrated into the KeySet.

Comment: Very impressive detective work! So if I take any 32 byte key and prepend  0x1a20 for an AES-256/GCM it should work?

Comment: @user3776598 - Yes, exactly. The key _0001...1e1f_ is representative for an _arbitrary_ key. After adding the prefix, the result must still be Base64 encoded.

Comment: It works beautifully. Thank you so much! If I may ask- how were you able to see that the first 2 bytes were fixed and were the length of the string from the base64 encoded string examples?

Comment: @user3776598 - As I said in my answer, unfortunately I haven't found any specification. I've deduced the meaning of the prefix by comparing different algorithms: For AES-128/GCM and AES-256/GCM the 1st byte is 0x1a, for ChaCha20Poly1305 it's 0x12. For AES-128/GCM the 2nd byte is 0x10, for AES-256/GCM and ChaCha20Poly1305 it's 0x20. Hence the conclusion that the 1st byte depends on the algorithm and that the 2nd byte indicates the key size. But the prefix can be more complex depending on the algorithm, i.e. the described procedure is valid for AES/GCM and must be adapted for other algorithms.

Comment: @user3776598 - I had somehow missed the Python tag. So I replaced the Java code snippets with Python code snippets. Apart from that, nothing has changed in content.

Answer (score 1):

While the other answer contains some really cool work, the actual answer is slightly different (and we should add it to the Wireformat description). The value stored here is a serialized proto of the type associated with the `KeyTypeManager` that has the corresponding `typeUrl` registered. In this case, it is the proto [`AesGcmKey`](https://github.com/google/tink/blob/master/proto/aes_gcm.proto). AES-GCM does not have any parameters other than the key size (which is implicitly defined when given an AES-GCM key), so the proto contains a single byte array. (This explains the superfluous looking first byte, it's the proto serialization of the version and a single `bytes` field. [XChaCha20Poly1305](https://github.com/google/tink/blob/master/proto/xchacha20_poly1305.proto) also has no additional parameters, I assume the reason you are seeing different prefixes is due to equivalent but unequal proto serialization, in theory the proto's name should not influence the serialization, and both use the same tags (1 for `version` and 3 for the raw key material) and `version` 0)

If you look at more complicated key types like [ECIES](https://github.com/google/tink/blob/master/proto/ecies_aead_hkdf.proto), the corresponding `value` would be far more involved (and containing even more serialized protos. It's protos all the way down).

We are planning to overhaul our key management layer somewhat substantially in the nearish future, which will make it easier to export/import keys that aren't using Tink's key format, without having to depend on proto definitions (which are supposed to be an internal implementation detail).